# How to Adjust right and left balance of audio while recording in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Accessibility. Here, you can adjust the left/right volume balance

But can we do it in our app with our code and Is there a way to adjust the left/right balance when playing a sound in flutter 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxw0c.png)

Comment: Which package are you using for playing normal audio?

Comment: audiofileplayer: ^1.0.3

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/audiofileplayer#-installing-tab-

Comment: got the answer? @MuhammadYounas

Comment: Were you able to achieve this @HarshBhavsar

Comment: I did not get any solution

Comment: https://github.com/iharshb/AudioSet/blob/master/ios/Classes/SwiftAudiosetPlugin.swift

It will help you. I have done some example. (Its only for iOS.) You will find-out easy process for android. @GibreelAbdullah